# Using '$(this)' In A Function

Tags: jquery, function, this

I am creating a menu that opens and closes using jQuery. In simple terms, it works like this:

```
function open_menu() {
    $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').css('display', 'block').stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '235px',
    }, 500);
}

function close_menu() {
    // close code here
}

status = 'closed'; // set the default menu status

$('a').click(function() {
    switch(status) {
        case 'closed':
            open_menu();
            break;
        case 'open':
            close_menu();
            break;
    }
}
```

If I take the contents of `open_menu()` and put it in place of `open_menu()` in the `.click()` event, every works as expected. If I use the code as show above, `$(this)` can not figure out that `.click()` fired it and the code does not run.

Is there something that I can do to have the `$(this)` selector negotiate what fired it while keeping it in `open_menu()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `this` that you refer to in `open_menu` is the context of the `open_menu` function, not the click handler of the link. You need to do something like this:

```
open_menu(this);

function open_menu(that) {
    $(that).next(...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use apply to set the value of `this` in the function.

```
open_menu.apply(this)
```

Comment: +1 Answers the question... *"Is there something that I can do to have the `$(this)` selector negotiate what fire it while keeping it in `open_menu()`"*

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pass it in as a parameter?

```
function open_menu($this) {
    $this.next('ul.sub-menu').css('display', 'block').stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '235px',
    }, 500);
}

function close_menu() {
    // close code here
}

status = 'closed'; // set the default menu status

$('a').click(function() {
    switch(status) {
        case 'closed':
            open_menu($(this));
            break;
        case 'open':
            close_menu();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I might have not done it properly.

I added `test = $(this);` right before the switch and passed that in. Sound right?