# How to select a child element of parent by jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select the "tbody" use jquery from function "tbodyExpand()" in below html code?
I tried to use  `$(this).closest('table').find('tbody')` but doesn't work.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <table class="table table-border table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>TITLE</b><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="tbodyExpand()" style="float: right;">EXPAND</a></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="hide">
        <tr>
            <td>ALT (U/L)</td>
            <td><input class="span1" name="ALT" value="" placeholder=""></td>              
        </tr>
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` referencing?

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122287/2812842

Comment: why are you combining inline `onclick` with jQuery in the first place? Just use jQuery  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `onclick="tbodyExpand.call(this)"` you can use:

```
  $(this).closest('table').find('tbody');
```

Otherwise `this` inside the function will be pointing to the global object (window) not the element clicked on.

Instead of writing inline handlers you can bind event using the selector.

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="expand floatRight">EXPAND</a>
```

CSS:

```
.floatRight{
     float: right;
 }
```

and

```
   $(function(){
       $('.expand').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); //Much better than doing javascript:void(0)
          var $tbody = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody');`
          //or $(this).closest('thead').next('tbody');
       });
   });
```

This way you can also separate out, css, js and html and avoid writing inline scripts/styles.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

**html**

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="tbodyExpand(this);" style="float: right;">EXPAND</a>
```

**javascript**

```
   function tbodyExpand(obj){
     // your other code goes here
     $(obj).closest('table').find('tbody');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

While all of these examples are legit, you could greatly simply your structure:

1. Give the active element an ID (in this case, I've given it `click`).
2. Bind to the `.click()` event of that ID:

   ```
   $('#click').click(function(e) {
       //you can do stuff here! and use $(this).
   });
   ```
3. Search for the element you want:

   `$(this).closest('table').find('tbody');`

Resulting in:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <table class="table table-border table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>CLICK EXPAND:</b> <a href="#" id='click' style="float: right;">EXPAND</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="hide">
            <tr>
                <td>ALT (U/L)</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="span1" name="ALT" value="" placeholder="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And your javascript (with jQuery loaded):

```
$('#click').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //blocks the default action of an <a> link.
    console.log($(this).closest('table').find('tbody'));
});
```

(Note that I slightly modified your code to make it easier to see what's going on).

Play around with it here http://jsfiddle.net/remus/VNpn7/