# Same function for keydown event and click event

Tags: jquery, onclick, this, keydown

I am trying to figure out how to trigger the same jQuery function clicking on an anchor tag or pressing the L key.

Here is the starting point:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','.jm-post-like',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    heart = jQuery(this);
    post_id = heart.data("post_id");
    jQuery.ajax({
       [NOTE: inside here there is some code using the variable 'heart'!]
    });
});
```

In this case, `heart` refers to `'.jm-post-like'`. To nest that code in a function, I had to change that var:

```
function likesystem(event) {
    heart = jQuery('.jm-post-like');
    post_id = heart.data("post_id");
    jQuery.ajax({
        .....
    });
}

jQuery('.jm-post-like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    likesystem(event);
});    

jQuery(document).keydown(function(event) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 76) { // L key code
        likesystem(event);
    }
});
```

I have to say that it works fine, except in those pages where there are multiple `'.jm-post-like'`. I've tried using `this` and `that` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122254/using-this-in-a-function), but in case of keydown `this` would refer to jQuery(document)!

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(this) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 76) { // L key code
        likesystem(this);
    }
});
```

I'm not really keen with jQuery, so any suggestion is greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: with more than one on the page, how can you know which one the current "L" press is directed at?

Comment: I too, want to know how you expect the page to know which `.jm-post-like` you're targeting in the event the user presses `L`?  Mouse-hover?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it which one.

You can use the event target.

```
function likesystem(event) {
    heart = jQuery(event.target);
```

Or you can use this, but you need to use event bubbling

```
jQuery(document).on("keydown", ".jm-post-like", function(event) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 76) { // L key code
        likesystem(this);
    }
});
```

BUT if they do not have an element in focus, pressing the "L" key really means nothing.

Comment: But, event.target is the same as saying $(this) within the keypress event, which would be `document`, wouldn't it?

Comment: sure, that works if you're within an input (textbox in your example), but I thought the assumption was that the system caret could be anywhere in the page, and he wants to set up a sort of hotkey scenario.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass in the jQuery object `$(this)` rather than the DOM object `this`?