# li not changing class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following tabs elements:

```html
<div class="sort_by_group group-3">
  <ul class="sort_by">
    <li class="ui-btn-active" data-order-by="price">Billigast<br>3.677 kr<div class="small_text">per person</div></li>
    <li class="" data-order-by="traveltime">Snabbast<br>4.476 kr<div class="small_text">per person</div></li>
    <li class="" data-order-by="best">Bäst<br>4.096 kr<div class="small_text">per person</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to change class on click second li and etc.

I try to do it like this:

```js
$('ul.sort_by li').off('click').on('click', function() {
  $('ul.sort_by li.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
  $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
  $("#filter_order_by").val($(this).attr('data-order-by'));
  Track.log_event(`Click order by: ${$(this).attr('data-order-by')}`);
  onUpdated();
}.bind(this));
```

But, it removes class and not add class to clicked element.

Where is my problem?

Comment: can you added a wroking snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `e` as an `event` for the function click, then use to add class the `e.target`:

```
 $('ul.sort_by li').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
  $('ul.sort_by li.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
  $(e.target).addClass('ui-btn-active');
  $("#filter_order_by").val($(this).attr('data-order-by'));
  Track.log_event(`Click order by: ${$(this).attr('data-order-by')}`);
  onUpdated();
}.bind(this));
```

So first change : `on('click', function(e) {` then  `$(e.target).addClass('ui-btn-active');`

Simple Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xvb2rsuv/2/

Comment: @Silco Cosider to accept my answer if is working for you now, maybe other people will got the same issue, and they will know that this is working.

Comment: Why isn't `this` being assigned to be the current target?  I thought jQuery did that unless you used arrow functions

Comment: hi @Pete you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122254/using-this-in-a-function