# JQuery-How to call external function with parameter in side onchange method in jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

How to call method inside onchange method in jquery. 
snippet below :

```
 $("#age").change(function(){

    var age=document.appform.age;

    if(age.value > 125){
        return false;
    }

    //i have some conditions same as above if condition 

    filtercustmerdata(age.value);
}
```

Method is :

```
function filtercustmerdata(ageval){
    alert("Age: "+ageval);// i got this value

    //But its not working
    $.getJSON("getCustDetails",{dateOfBirth: ageval}, function(data){
        alert("data: "+data);
        var data2=JSON.stringify(data);
        alert("Stringfy data: "+data2);
        var str = "";
        $.each(data.custdetails, function(key, value) {
            var custid=value[0];
            var custname=value[1];

            str = str+ "<option value="+custid+ ">"+ custname+ "</option>"; 
        });  
        $("#CustDetails").html(str);//Dropdown
     });

}
```

The `filtercustmerdata` method is called but

> $.getJSON

is not working?
I didn't get error/exception?

Please help me!

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: I don't think your method  no have error/exception. In filtercustmerdata, $(this).val() is error becase $(this) isn't  your $("#age") , it is you refer to in filtercustmerdata is the context of the filtercustmerdata function. you can check [Using this in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122254/using-this-in-a-function)

Comment: You might want to verify your endpoint url "getCustDetails" for the get method to call. Might be it never finds one there by returning 404 not found. Check if it needs some processing like the context paths or authentication.

Comment: and yes, as per @minh-nguyen  $(this).val() is incorrect. You have already fetched that in calling function.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Mistake is mine typing.i corrected myself. edited $(this).val() to ageval . But actual problem is  $.getJSON its not working.